# How to get predicate values

Tags: prolog

For example I have:

```
pos(10, 20).
```

How can i write the predicate which returns the first pos term(10).

```
 get_pos_x(Pos) :- % should return the first pos param(10).
```

Example of work:

```
get_pos_x(pos(10,20)) :- % should write 10.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a *predicate* `pos(10, 20).` and a *term* `pos(10, 20)`.

For the *predicate*, this would be the code:

```
pos(10, 20).
```

And this would be the execution of the code:

```
:- pos(X, 20), write(X), nl.
```

For the *term*, this would be the code:

```
get_pos_x(pos(X, _)) :-
    write(X), nl.
```

And this would be the execution of the code:

```
:- get_pos_x(pos(10, 20)).
```